# Назначить привелегии пользователю базы дынных MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure

Добрый день.

Установил себе базу данных MySQL на Azure. Пытаюсь импортировать данные с другой базы через MySQL WorkBench. Выдает ошибку: `select command denied to user ... for table ...`. Зашел в phpMyAdmin и попытался добавить прав.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'eu-cdbr-azure-west-d.cloudapp.net';`

Получил ошибку: `#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation`

В чем может быть причина?

Спасибо.

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно, что добавлять пользователей нужно через портал.

Comment: Из под какого пользователя вы выполняете операции и как он был создан? Есть ли у вас доступ к root-аккаунту?

Comment: Связался с поддержкой Microsoft, говорят, что базу так нельзя импортировать, поскольку MySQL не их родная и они ее бурут у СlearDB. Вот такое пояснение. Говорят, что можно только только из командной строки (Kudu). Так и сделал.